# Vector calculus identity for $\nabla\times(\vec{b}\cdot\nabla)\vec{b}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm going through a paper on turbulence and in it the author uses the following $$ \nabla\times(\vec{b}\cdot\nabla)\vec{b}=(\vec{b}\cdot\nabla)(\nabla\times\vec{b})-\left((\nabla\times\vec{b})\cdot\nabla\right)\vec{b} $$ however I have tried to verify this with both vector analysis identities and using suffix notation and I can't seem to do so. I wondered if anyone could either show why it holds or correct it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the curl of a vector field and the divergence of a vector field? I'm assuming $\vec{b}$ is your given vector field.

Comment: Sorry I meant I used both methods, as in manipulating standard vector identities and using suffix notation. The specific identity I tried to apply was $$ \nabla\times(\psi\vec{A})=\psi\nabla\times\vec{A}+\nabla\psi\times\vec{A} $$ since $ \vec{b}\cdot\nabla$ is a scalar this seemed the most appropriate. However this didn't yield the correct result for me.

Comment: Yes I do know how to compute the curl and the divergence and yes b is my vector. But it is an algebraic quantity and so I do not have numeric values for the vector so can't do a direct calculation.

Comment: Well $\vec{b}$ should be a vector field. Not sure what you mean by an algebraic quantity, but write out $\vec{b}$ in terms of its three components.

Comment: I realise that you could do that to verify the equivalence. But I was more hoping for an explanation of how you get from the left hand side to the right hand side using standard vector manipulation. eg identities, product rules etc.

Comment: @MathNewbie That is not the case, since $\nabla$ is an operator.

Comment: The rules for vectors change when you use operators rather than standard vectors. I.e. $ \nabla $ is the del operator $ (\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}) $ (in 3 dimensions) and so because it is a derivative you need some notion of a product rule which is what I wrote is meant to be. I got it from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Second_derivatives and although I know wikipedia isn't always the most reliable I've never had problems with this particular page before.

Comment: @Daniel My mistake. I always thought it could also be treated as a vector and the operator of partial derivatives.

Comment: @Nick For the most part, I find wikipedia pretty reliable except in the case where the page states that some updating is needed on a particular page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** It turns out the identity is incorrect.
Consider the vector field $\vec{b}=\begin{pmatrix}xy\\0\\xy\end{pmatrix}$ (it doesn't work)

Comment: Thank you! Although it is in fact that last bit that I was having trouble with!

Comment: Perhaps I was being a bit hopeful in saying this hopefully isn't too hard... I can't seem to verify it! I'll leave this up for the time being and come back to it when I work it out.

Comment: EDIT: It turns out the identity is false. See the above for a counterexample (I leave verifying it as an exercise to the reader!)

Comment: Ahhh yes you are right! Now to see how badly this error affects the paper!!

Comment: I'm curious as to what the actual identity is. Perhaps there's a typo or something of that sort.

Comment: I shall ask my supervisor about it and let you know when he clears it up.

Comment: Thanks, I look forward to it!

Answer (score 0):

Extremely late comment, but this identity is true if the flow is incompressible, so $\nabla \cdot b =0$.